# import JavaFX project on Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, javafx, javafxports

i made a JavaFX program on eclipse who works well, now I want to convert this program to an android app. I used Gradle with eclipse and i got a file "build.gradle" so I import this project on Android Studio by importing "build.gradle" like eclipse said. But now I don't know how to convert my JavaFX program to an android app and I don't know how to use Android Studio. Someone can help me ?

Here's my project structure on Android Studio :

```
--Puzzle_FX
  --.idea
    --copyright
        profiles_settings.xml
    --scopes
        scope_settings.xml
    .name
    compiler.xml
    encodings.xml
    gradle.xml
    misc.xml
    modules.xml
    vcs.xml
    workspace.xml
  --.settings
      org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
  --bin
    --org
      --puzzle
        --colors
            CColors.class
        --commands
            commands.txt
            SmartInput.class
        --controllers
            Controller.class
        --fonts
            apple.ttf
            bit.ttf
            pixelmix.ttf
            pixelmix_bold.ttf
            wendy.ttf
        --frames
            Console.class
            CreateFrames.class
            ShowGame.class
        --models
            Cel.class
            CelExtended.class
            Game.class
            Grid.class
        --nodes
            GCanevasFX.class
            GCelFX.class
            GPolygonFX.class
            GShadowFX.class
        --styles
            style.css
        --texts
            Input.class
            Output.class
            pixelmix.ttf
        --views
            Overview.fxml
            RootLayout.fxml
      MainApp.class
  --doc
    ...
      documentation
    ...
  --gradle
    --wrapper
        gradle-wrapper.jar
        gradle-wrapper.properties
  --src
    ...
      all my .java file
    ...
  .classpath
  .project
  build.gradle
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  local.properties
  Puzzle_FX.iml
--External Libraries
```

This is what i got when i used gradle on eclipse

Comment: Have a look at the [JavaFXPorts - Getting Started guide](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started)

Comment: You should take a look at http://robovm.com/javafx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert JavaFX project to Android, without using Android Studio, and keeping the JavaFX sources, then you should have a look at the [JavaFXPorts](http://javafxports.org/page/home) project.

You just need to include one single plugin on your build.gradle.

Have a look at the links provided here [JavaFXPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafxports/info).

Also you can check this blog [post](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2015/03/javafx-on-mobile-dream-come-true.html) with one use case.

Even if you are using Eclipse, you may consider using Gluon's [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-plugin-for-netbeans/) for NetBeans, that will create for you a JavaFX project where you can add your sources, and even have Android native services.

Keep in mind Android runs Dalvik VM, so you can't use Java 8 new features (streams).

Comment: Thank you for your advice I will watching this, but i cant convert my javafx project into android app with Android Studio ?

Comment: Well, you mentioned you didn't know how to use it... In the [samples](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src) repository there is one project (Kokos) that is done in Android Studio, so it is possible. But with the jfxmobile plugin you don't need it... you can build the apk from your IDE.

Comment: So with JFXPorts i can use the jfxmobile plugin and build my apk from eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, sure. I recommend using NetBeans, since the Gluon plugin creates a new project for you, but you can check the projects from the mentioned samples. If you don't need any native service have a look at HelloWorld. If you do, then have a look at HelloPlatform.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I will watch JFXPorts and Gluon, your blog is simple too, you worked well :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, as it could be useful for others too.